# Why hasn't my 15 year old tamarind tree ever borne fruit?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, fruits

In my garden, there is a tamarind tree, which is 15 years old. It has never produced fruits, not even a single time. What can be the issue with it?

There are around 10 coconut trees and 2 mango trees at a necessary distance. Those are all fine. Irrigation is done regularly. How can I improve this situation?

Comment: Do you get flowers on the tree?  What is your location?

Comment: No flowers. Location is an interior village in India.

Answer (score 0):

If it has never flowered,

- Either there is something defective about it
- Or it needs fertilisation, especially Nitrogen and Phosphorus.